# Scrolling through a div with navbar

Tags: javascript, html

I have a navbar and a div which contains Text with headlines. With my navbar I can scroll them into view by `<href="#entry">` and with js I highlight the clicked element. But when the user scrolls by themself the navbar does not automatically update the viewed article. 
It works like this:
HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
 <a class="tableentry" href="#article1">article 1</a><br>
 <a class="tableentry" href="#article2">article 2</a><br>
 ...
</div>
<div id="articles">
 <div id="article1">
  Some stuff...
 </div>
 <div id="article2">
  Some stuff...
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS is irrelevant I think (there is only a colour difference between tableentry and tableentry.active)...

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("tableentry"), function (e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function () {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("active"), function (current) {
            current.className = current.className.replace(" active", "");
        });
        this.className += " active";
    })
});
```

pls do not answer with jQuery. I don't want to use it. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself (thx dad)

```
let content_div = document.getElementById("mainbody");
content_div.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    let body_div_bounds = content_div.getBoundingClientRect();
    let element = content_div.getElementsByClassName("article");
    for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
        let article_div_bounds = element[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        if (article_div_bounds.y >= 0 && article_div_bounds.y < body_div_bounds.height){
            let active_entry = document.getElementsByClassName("tableentry active")[0];
            if(active_entry != element[i]){
                active_entry.className = active_entry.className.replace(" active", "");
                console.log(active_entry.className + " " + active_entry.id);
                document.getElementById(element[i].id + "_entry").className += " active";
            }
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

had to add an id to the tableenties.